# Call a script PHP using entire link (Require, include, ...)

Tags: php

I would like to know if there is an alternative to include or require because I would like to access some scripts that I have put in another server for example :

```
require("https://example.com/test/verification_proof.php");
```

This will not work, and will generate an exception (This link is wrong just for the test) would you have alternatives to propose to me please?

Comment: It makes no sense to use a URL with `require()`. `require` needs the source code, but accessing a PHP script through a webserver executes the script and returns the output, not the source.

Comment: In general, webservers don't provide any way for you to access script source code. This is a security measure.

Comment: You could run `curl` or `file_get_contents` but that would be the contents after the file was compiled by the server's software (apache, etc.).

Comment: You just need to copy the files to each server

Comment: Do you think Ajax could work? With a little fiddling?

Comment: No. It's still making a http request, so it would still execute the script and return the output instead of compiling into the one you want. And ajax runs from the browser, so the result would never go anywhere near the php you're wanting to include it in. A browser running JavaScript has no use for a php file. So that idea doubly makes no sense. Stop trying to find bizarre workarounds and just deploy copies of the files to both servers, like everyone else. That's how you run the same thing on on servers - you just copy it onto each one. Why is that a problem, specifically?

Comment: its better you just use the script as an API endpoint instead of messing around with `require`